# Get the same input with EOF terminator as with .empty() function

Tags: c++, string, input, stream, getline

I want to get user input, and the number of characters that are given is important. I get a satisfying result with `input.empty()` but it terminates after I press Enter. I want it to terminate after i specifically type `Ctrl+D`.

```
1) do{                                   2) while(std::getline(std::cin, input)){
     getline(std::cin, input);                  buffer += input;
     buffer += input;                           buffer += '\n';
     buffer += '\n';                        }  
   }while(!input.empty());                  std::cin.ignore();
```

Other than the Enter terminator the first code work as I want it to, and the second one has a character more, which I'm not sure what it exactly is, but it does end when I type `Ctrl+D`. `input` and `buffer` are both `std::string`. So how can I get the same result as `input.empty()`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your question, you claim that the second code snippet has one character more. Are you sure that it is not the opposite? Is it not so that the first one has one character more?

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you claim that the second code snippet produces one character more in `buffer` than the first code snippet. However, I assume that this statement is false. It is the first one which should have one character more, for the following reason:

When `std::getline` encounters end-of-file after reading at least one character, then both code snippets will behave the same way.

However, if `std::getline` encounters end-of-file before reading at least one character (i.e. if it is encountered at the start of the line), then the behavior of the two code snippets is different: The first code snippet will write an additional newline character to `buffer`, before the loop gets terminated, whereas the second code snippet will terminate immediately.

In other words, the first code snippet produces one character too much, because its logic is wrong. Therefore, I suggest that you use the second snippet. However, it is unclear what `std::cin.ignore();` in the second code snippet is supposed to accomplish, because the function `std::getline` has already removed the newline character from the input stream (if it existed). Also, calling `std::ignore` when the end of the stream has already been reached will probably have no effect. Therefore, you should probably remove that line.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is remove the last '\n' from the buffer string in the second code by adding cin.ignore() but it doesn't seem to work(maybe it isn't supposed to this way). in the first code i don't get the last new line in the buffer. i think i know this is true because when i print out the number of characters i entered in the terminal the first code gives one less(which is supposed to happen) then the second one

Comment: @r3k0j: The line `std::cin.ignore();` will remove the next character from the input stream. It will not remove any character from `buffer`. If you want to remove the last character from `buffer`, then you should use [`buffer.pob_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/pop_back) instead. However, it is normally desirable to keep the newline character of the last line.